# Tkinter -How to get a LABEL to respond to a certain function that has been CALLED by a BUTTON

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I am currently using `Tkinter` for a GUI. I am working on a `LOGIC GATES` program where I ask the user for two inputs (1 or 0). I have created 5 functions (`orF`, `andF`, `nandF`, `norF`, `xorF`) and used the `GRID` method to position my widgets.

I tried getting the label which I have called "al", to present the result once a BUTTON (OR, AND, NAND, NOR, XOR) has been clicked.

The "al" widget isn't responding to the functions and some of my labels have been cut off.

How can I create a program that enable the user to click on a button in order for the result (1 or 0) to be presented onto another label?

**Here's the code:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Logic Gates Calculator")

Title = Label(root, text ="Using machine to calculate the correct LOGIC Gate 
from inputs",
              fg = "blue",
              bg = "#00ffff",
              font = "Calibri 22 bold italic")

Title.grid(row=0, column=0)

al = Label(root, text ="The result",
           fg = "white",
           bg = "blue",
           font = "Helvetica 22 bold")

al.grid(row=0, column=1)

first_il = Label(root, text ="Enter your first input: ",
                 fg = "white",
                 bg = "dark blue",
                 font = "Calibri 18 bold italic")

first_il.grid(row=2, column=0)

first_ie = Entry(root)
first_ie.grid(row=2, column=1)

second_il = Label(root, text ="Enter your second input: ",
                 fg = "white",
                 bg = "dark blue",
                 font = "Calibri 18 bold italic")

second_il.grid(row=3, column=0)

second_ie = Entry(root)
second_ie.grid(row=3, column=1)

def orF():
    input1 = first_ie.get()
    input2 = second_ie.get()

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "0") or (input2 == "1" and input1 == 
    "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="1")

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "1"):
        al = Label(root, text ="1")

    if (input1 == "0" and input2 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    else:
        al = Label(root, text ="Invalid input")

def andF():
    input1 = first_ie.get()
    input2 = second_ie.get()

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "0") or (input2 == "1" and input1 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "1"):
        al = Label(root, text ="1")

    if (input1 == "0" and input2 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    else:
        al = Label(root, text ="Invalid input")

def norF():
    input1 = first_ie.get()
    input2 = second_ie.get()

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "0") or (input2 == "1" and input1 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "1"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    if (input1 == "0" and input2 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="1")

    else:
        al = Label(root, text ="Invalid input")

def nandF():
    input1 = first_ie.get()
    input2 = second_ie.get()

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "0") or (input2 == "1" and input1 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="1")

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "1"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    if (input1 == "0" and input2 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="1")

    else:
        al = Label(root, text ="Invalid input")

def xorF(): 
    input1 = first_ie.get()
    input2 = second_ie.get()

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "0") or (input2 == "1" and input1 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="1")

    if (input1 == "1" and input2 == "1"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    if (input1 == "0" and input2 == "0"):
        al = Label(root, text ="0")

    else:
        al = Label(root, text ="Invalid input")



or_button = Button(root, text ="Click for OR",
                    fg = "blue",
                    bg = "yellow",
                    font = "Calibri 20 bold italic",
                    command = orF)

or_button.grid(row =1, column =1)

and_button = Button(root, text ="Click for AND",
                    fg = "blue",
                    bg = "red",
                    font = "Calibri 20 bold italic",
                    command = andF)

and_button.grid(row =1, column =2)


nor_button = Button(root, text ="Click for NOR",
                    fg = "blue",
                    bg = "green",
                    font = "Calibri 20 bold italic",
                    command = norF)

nor_button.grid(row =1, column =3)



nand_button = Button(root, text ="Click for NAND",
                    fg = "blue",
                    bg = "orange",
                    font = "Calibri 20 bold italic",
                    command = nandF)

nand_button.grid(row =1, column =4)


xor_button = Button(root, text ="Click for XOR",
                    fg = "blue",
                    bg = "Magenta",
                    font = "Calibri 20 bold italic",
                    command = xorF)


xor_button.grid(row =1, column =5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are *reassigning* `al` every time to a *new* `Label` object that is not being managed.  You should be updating `al` based on your results like [`al.config(text="your results here")`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) in each of your functions.  Another way to do this would be to use [`tk.StringVar()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).  I don't currently have the time to go through the rest of your code but that should update your `al` `Label` now.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the code down to a [mcve]? I'm guessing that you could illustrated your problem with just one or two buttons rather than five. Also, it doesn't seem like other widgets such as the title are relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Thanks, yep that did the job. Yes I should have only gave parts of my code..